# Spring security 4 not intercepting role assigned Url after login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have just upgrade spring security from 2 to 4. Some custom filters used for login,remember me and single sign on process.
Two login mechanism used in my application.
First simple form login and second SSO login.
This is my securityContext.xml

```
<!-- enable method-level security via annotation -->
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="disabled"/>

<!-- secure the web layer -->


<sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/styles/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/qlogin.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/qloginWait/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/contract/ServiceContractPDFView.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/unsubscribe_sbpqm_newsletter.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/subscription_form.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/subscription_thankyou.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/related_analysts.jsp" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/login.jsp" security="none" />


<sec:http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"> 
    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
    </sec:session-management>
    <sec:headers>
      <sec:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
      <sec:content-type-options disabled="true"/>
     </sec:headers>
    <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <sec:custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" ref="rememberMeProcessingFilter"/> 
    <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customizedFormLoginFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="singleSignOnFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <sec:anonymous username="anonymousUser" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</sec:http>



<!--name of my authenticationManager is authenticationManager-->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customizedFormLoginFilter" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter" >
    <!--Here it is the custom authenticationManager, login magic goes here -->
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager"/> 
    <property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
    <property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" /> 
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myAuthenticationManager" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" />

<bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener"/>

<!--My authentication entry point, can be replaced easily if we are doing custom commence of invalid auths.-->
<bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint"
class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="successHandler" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/indexCustomer.jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
</bean>
<!-- Override RememberMeProcessingFilter to allow application of other business logic (update login count when user returns to the site --> 

<bean id="rememberMeProcessingFilter" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomRememberMeProcessingFilter"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="rememberMeServices"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="signleSignOnService" class="com.myPro.sage.sso.dynamo.SsoDbStorage">
</bean>
<bean id="singleSignOnFilter"
      class="com.myPro.test.spring.SingleSignOnFilter">
    <property name="signleSignOnService" ref="signleSignOnService"/>
    <!--<property name="authenticationProviderFacade" ref="authenticationProviderFacade"/>-->
    <property name="userService" ref="myProUserServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="ssoUserUrl">
        <value>/sso</value>
    </property>
    <!-- Code Review Starts -->
    <property name="ssoTargetUrl">
        <value>/search/ServiceContractSearch.do</value>
    </property>
    <!-- Code Review Ends -->
    <property name="ssoFailureUrl">
        <value>/login.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="123456"/>
</bean>


<!-- Remember me Authentication Defines which remember me implementation to use - in this case using a database table to log 'remembered' tokens --> 
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomUserDetailsService" > </bean>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg value="springRocks"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
</bean>


<!-- Uses a database table to maintain a set of persistent login data --> 

<bean id="jdbcTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl"> 
    <property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false" /> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider"> 
    <constructor-arg value="springRocks"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" >
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true" />
</bean> 

<bean id="mySecurityContextHandler" class="com.myPro.test.security.CustomSecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>  

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"> 
    <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp" /> 
     <constructor-arg> 
        <list>
            <ref bean="mySecurityContextHandler" /> 
            <ref bean="rememberMeServices" /> 
            <ref bean="securityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationLoggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener"/>

<bean id="_sessionFixationProtectionFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"> 
    <property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```

changed securityContext.xml according spring Security 4.
if I removed this filter 
sec:custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="singleSignOnF
ilter"

 from http, application worked fine. All Urls accessible after login.
If I add this line  then pattern (/**) not working for me. Blank page will come.
Please help to solve this problem

Comment: The order of your `intercept-url` is important..  The `/**` mapping should always come last... The order in which they are defined is also the order in which they are consulted. Also in Spring Security 4 if you want no security add a new `http` element with a `pattern` attribute and `security="none"` attribute instead of an intercept-url with `filters-"none"`.

Comment: Sorry it's my older securityContext file.  I have already update this xml file. I am editing this please check now.

Comment: Denium  I have edit my securityContext file please look at this again.

Comment: enable DEBUG logging to see what is happening.

Comment: Nothing coming in logging file only blank page showing.

Comment: Exception isn't important. Enable debug logging to see the flow of the request through the filters, so that you can see what is wrong. Make sure your filter works with Spring Security 4 and that it uses appropriate constructors and overrides.